# PGF-TikZ named shape error

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I run the LaTeX code below, I get the error

> Package pgf Error: No shape named h02 is known

Meanwhile, I have tagged the `\node` object with the label `h\x0` in the for loop. Which seems to me the right thing that should be done. I even uncommented the line with the `\coordinate` command and changed `h02.west` to `v02.west` but still I get the error

> Package pgf Error: No shape named v02 is known

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={rectangle,draw=blue,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5mm},scale = 1.6,every lower node part/.style={font=\tiny}]

% Horizontal Vertices
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}
{
    \draw (\x,0) circle (0.03cm);
    \fill (\x,0) circle (0.03cm);
    \node (h\x0) at (\x,0) [place] {};
    % \coordinate (v\x0) at (\x,0);
}
\node [left, every lower node part] at (h02.west) {$N_{1}=3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi evansdoe! I suppose you mean `(h0\x)` rather than `(h\x0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the error. The name tag `(h02.west)` should rather be `(h20.west)`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={rectangle,draw=blue,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5mm},scale = 1.6,every lower node part/.style={font=\tiny}]

% Horizontal Vertices
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}
{
    \draw (\x,0) circle (0.03cm);
    \fill (\x,0) circle (0.03cm);
    \node (h\x0) at (\x,0) [place] {};
    % \coordinate (v\x0) at (\x,0);
}
\node [left, every lower node part] at (h20.west) {$N_{1}=3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```